# Is robocopy a valid tool for publishing sites onto multiple servers?

Tags: asp.net, robocopy

I'm currently trying to find a good solution for publishing a web site onto multiple load balanced servers.

As it stands (from msdn) VS itself does not support it free house without me editing the installation templates. As I want t oavoid that, I'm looking for alternative ideas. One of them was the following:

- I publish onto a single server
- I robocopy all changed files to all other servers (automatically)

Now my question there is: Is it enough to just copy the files from one server to all others (and thus robocopy a valid tool there)?  Or does the publish process do more than just copy files onto a server ? 
*(That I have to initially configure the applications one single time anyway is clear to me).*

Answer (score 0):

The VS publish process 'just' does

- Build and choose the files to publish
- Web config transform
- File Copy

It assumes that the web application you are publishing to is already configured and does no configuration for you.

So I would say **yes**. If you have published to one server then the first two steps are done for you, and robocopy is all you need for the further servers.

The 'bigger' solution is a CI pipeline using a tool such as Octopus, TeamCity or Jenkins. What they offer over your script is good control of history and ease of rollback. And better control if you have multiple people publishing.